How does postgres store BYTEA data and how to calculate real size of the stored data
I've run the following query:
create table some_table (col1 bytea);
insert into some_table (col1) values (repeat('x', 1024 * 1024 * 1023)::bytea);
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('some_table'));

The result is 12 MB.
I expected that the size of the table will be about 1GB (1024 * 1024 * 1023) but pg_size_pretty() shows just 12MB.
So could someone please explain how the data are stored and why I see 12MB instead of 1 GB?
Also if there is a way to find out the real size of the stored data?
I would like to know it because
select * from some_table;

ends with the error message:

SQL Error [XX000]: Error: invalid memory alloc request size 2145386499.


I do understand that a string representation of that BYTEA data requires more than 1GB and I would like to know if it is possible to successfully perform a select query before it fails. Unfortunately pg_size_pretty() does not give any answer to this question.
I will be glad if someone can shed some light on this. Thanks.

See Toast

In other words you are seeing the effects of compression. Try alter table some_table alter column col1 set storage external;, delete from some_table;, insert into some_table (col1) values (repeat('x', 1024 * 1024 * 1023)::bytea); and then SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('some_table')); . In my test that ended up with 1074 MB.

As already clarified by @Adrian Klaver, the size difference you see is because of transparent compression in PostgreSQL:

The TOAST management code recognizes four different strategies for
storing TOAST-able columns on disk:

PLAIN prevents either compression or out-of-line storage. This is the only possible strategy for columns of non-TOAST-able data types.

EXTENDED allows both compression and out-of-line storage. This is the default for most TOAST-able data types. Compression will be attempted first, then out-of-line storage if the row is still too big.

EXTERNAL allows out-of-line storage but not compression. Use of EXTERNAL will make substring operations on wide text and bytea columns faster (at the penalty of increased storage space) because these operations are optimized to fetch only the required parts of the out-of-line value when it is not compressed.

MAIN allows compression but not out-of-line storage. (Actually,out-of-line storage will still be performed for such columns, but only as a last resort when there is no other way to make the row small enough to fit on a page.)



Using pg_column_compression() and pg_column_toast_chunk_id()(v17+) You can observe the lengths and sizes of the values below and see how long they get stored raw, when they get compressed, then both compressed and moved to TOAST. Note that the thresholds depend on your cluster setup:
demo at db-fiddle
select ctid
     , left(convert_from(col1,'UTF8'),20) sample
     , length(col1)
     , pg_column_compression(col1)
     , pg_column_toast_chunk_id(col1) --v17+
     , pg_size_pretty(pg_column_size(col1)::bigint)
from some_table;




ctid
sample
length
pg_column_compression
pg_column_toast_chunk_id
pg_size_pretty




(0,2)
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
1024


1028 bytes


(0,3)
cccccccccccccccccccc
2048
pglz

35 bytes


(0,4)
dddddddddddddddddddd
131072
pglz

1513 bytes


(0,5)
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
262144
pglz
16391
3009 bytes



As to the error you're trying to work around:

SQL Error [XX000]: Error: invalid memory alloc request size 2145386499


You can try to split up the long values with substr() and paginate through them:
demo at db<>fiddle
select some_table.ctid
     , byte_offset
     , convert_from(substr(col1,byte_offset,(2^18)::int),'UTF8') as a_slice
from some_table
cross join lateral
generate_series(0,length(col1),(2^18)::int)as byte_offset
order by byte_offset limit 5;




ctid
byte_offset
a_slice




(0,2)
0
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


(0,2)
262144
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


(0,2)
524288
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


(0,2)
786432
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


(0,2)
1048576
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx



